# Could not cast value of type 'LLAppDelegateProxy'

Tags: ios, swift, localytics

I have integrated the Localtyics iOS SDK. After this I am getting the error like below:
Could not cast value of type 'LLAppDelegateProxy'

It means I am unable to get a reference of the App delegate object. I am in trouble now because I want Localytics & want a reference object of App delegate as well.

Does any body know a solution of this?

Comment: I got the solution. Localytics has provided solution in their documentation.https://docs.localytics.com/dev/ios.html#analytics-callbacks-ios

Comment: Maybe their documentation changed - the link that should get you right to this is https://help.uplandsoftware.com/localytics/dev/ios.html#swift-ios

Answer (score 12):

Localytics replaces your AppDelegate behind-the-scenes with their proxy class 
(`LLAppDelegateProxy`).  Localytics suggests creating a static reference to your original AppDelegate for access like so:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    static var originalAppDelegate: AppDelegate!

    // ...

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        AppDelegate.originalAppDelegate = self

        // ...

}
```

Access using:

```
AppDelegate.originalAppDelegate.someMethod()
```

Comment: this helped me thanks , but I am facing issue in LoginWithFacebook functionality as Localytics replaces AppDelegate behind-the-scenes with their proxy class (LLAppDelegateProxy) , my openURL method from AppDelegate doesn't call (It works fine if I remove the Localytics from my project )

Comment: @VivekShah You should ask a new question.