# Getting crash "Could not cast value of type 'LLAppDelegateProxy' "

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, appdelegate, localytics

I have a method in my AppDelegate file. Which I was calling from another class. But after implementing Localytics I am getting a crash. Here is how I was calling the method.

```
 let delegate = UIApplicatin.shared.delegate as ! AppDelegate
 delegate.myFunction()
```

I have tried [this answer from Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37915873/could-not-cast-value-of-type-llappdelegateproxy). Its does not crash the app but method is not called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working. Actually I was missing the line in `didFinishLauncihingWithOptions` as mentioned in [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37915873/could-not-cast-value-of-type-llappdelegateproxy). We have to do this.

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        AppDelegate.originalAppDelegate = self
    }
```